# KIA soul 2013, has a clack-clack-clack noise when the motor is on. As I ramp up the revolutions the clacking frequency increases. Is this urgent?

Tags: noise, kia, motors, mileage, soul

Bought the car a year ago. I think I remember hearing the noise from the beginning, Motor has 180K miles, have done 2 oil changes. There is no recall notice from NHTSA. Car is stick shift, runs normal. I think the noise is more pronounced in the morning when its cold. I think the noise is getting more pronounced.

I don't have a trustworthy mechanic I can ask for advise and I fear if I dont know much I can get ripped off if I just ask for advice on the noise and not knowing what might be the cuase. This is a daily short commute car. I do not plan to use it extensively other than a few miles daily and I don't speed. I want to maximize it's lifespan with a minimum investment on repairs or upgrades.

This is basically my radio flyer cart with motor, gets me from A to B with the least amount of cost. Any recommendations on what literature to go thru or what videos I can look for to get educated on troubleshooting this kind of noises and how to decide if it's critical to take it to mechanic or if it can wait until its next oil change?

Comment: Read about Kia "piston slap" here: https://www.google.com/search?q=kia+piston+slap

Comment: Check reviews, maybe you can find a mechanic who will die a "diagnosis" for a small fee?

Comment: Can you add a recording of the noise?